# Returning values from a PDO function

Tags: php, pdo

I have this function in an included file

```
function ListModules() {
try {
        global $DBH;
        $ListModules->query("SELECT * FROM modules");
        $ListModules->execute();
        return $ListModules->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}  }
```

Then I'm trying to echo them into a  drop down box like this:

```
echo "<select name='deletelist' class='form-control'>
        <option value='0'>Choose a module to delete</option>";
        while($modulelist = ListModules()) {
            echo "<option value='".$moduelist['id']."'>".$modulelist['name']."</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: `$moduelist['id']` is missing a `l`, is that a copy/paste typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListModules()` return `array`

```
while($modulelist = ListModules())
```

is equal to

```
while(true)
```

having to cycle an array, in your case it is better to use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$modulelist = ListModules();

echo "<select name='deletelist' class='form-control'>
    <option value='0'>Choose a module to delete</option>";

foreach( $modulelist as $module ){
     echo "<option value='".$module ['id']."'>".$module ['name']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I was also missing the `$DBH->query` too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because your function return an array of some sort, so your loop is the equivalent to:

```
while ($modulelist = array(1, 2, 3)) {
```

Which basically means that it would always be true.

What you probably want is a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: I thought that's what I would need since if I put this into the file itself without the function, I can use $modulelist = $ListModules->fetch and it works fine.

Comment: You should understand the difference between types in PHP. `fetch` returns a single row, and advances the internal point in the PDO statement. `fetchAll` returns an array of all results.

Comment: So `fetch` in effect does it one by one, but `fetchAll` gets it all at once?

Comment: Exactly. You should read the manual entries of functions you are using.